# How to add a dictionary entry to another dictionary in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have these three dictionaries

```
    dictLibraries.Add("SVSU", "Zahnow Library")
    dictLibraries.Add("BR", "Fleschner Memorial Library")
    dictLibraries.Add("SDJ", "Scott D. James Technical Repository")

    dictBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")
    dictBooks.Add("102", "Interpretive Klingon Poetry")
    dictBooks.Add("103", "Doing More With Less - Navel Lint Art")
    dictBooks.Add("104", "Data Structures for Fun and Profit")
    dictBooks.Add("105", "Programming with the Bidgoli")

    dictMedia.Add("201", "CD - IEEE Computer: the Hits")
    dictMedia.Add("202", "DVD - The Pirates of Silicon Valley")
    dictMedia.Add("203", "DVD - Databases and You: the Video Experience")
```

Then I want to make another dictionary

```
Public mynesteddict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

Inside this dictionary I want   "SVSU", dictboooks("101", "Zen and the art of appliance Wiring")

How do I do this

Comment: Far be it from me to criticise your philosophy, but have you considered using a relational database instead?

Comment: its a assignment that uses dictionaries.. otherwise it would be so much easier

Comment: Ah, so you're bound by the constraints of someone else's stupidity. That happens a lot - welcome to the wonderful world of programming. ;)

Comment: BTW, +1 for `Doing More With Less - Navel Lint Art`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a Dictionary as same as `dictbooks` (`dictbooks_1`),
2. copy what you want from dictbooks inside it,
3. and then add the values to `mynesteddict`

   ```
   Dim mynesteddict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
   Dim dictBooks_1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
   dictBooks_1.Add("101", dictBooks("101"))
   mynesteddict.Add("SVSU", dictBooks_1)
   ```